# Looking for a book recommendation out of a pre-defined list

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

I'm looking for a book that has an overview of physics.

I gathered a list of books I think that might be suitable for me:

- Basic Physics: A Self-Teaching Guide:
  [https://www.amazon.com/Basic-Physics-Self-Teaching-Guide-Guides-ebook-dp-B08HHFZ1M8/dp/B08HHFZ1M8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08HHFZ1M8)
- The Character of Physical Law:
  [https://www.amazon.com/Character-Physical-Law-MIT-Press/dp/0262533413](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262533413)
- For the Love of Physics:
  [https://www.amazon.com/Love-Physics-Rainbow-Journey-Through/dp/145160713X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/145160713X)
- Physics I For Dummies:
  [https://www.amazon.com/Physics-Dummies-Math-Science/dp/1119293596](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119293596)

As a first physics book, which one of them do you recommend?